Exploring Plancherel measure decay rates linked to a specific $AD(\Gamma)$ range
In this paper on the amenability constant of Fourier algebras  Theorem 1.5 presents a formula connecting $AD(\Gamma)$, the anti-diagonal constant of a countable virtually abelian group $\Gamma$, to its Plancherel measure $\nu$. Specifically, it states that
$$AD(\Gamma) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} n^2 \nu(\Omega_n)$$
where $\Omega_n$ represents the set of irreducible representations of dimension $n$.
I'm particularly interested in the case where $3/2 < AD(\Gamma) < 2$. From the paper, I understand this forces $\nu(\Omega_1)$, the measure of one-dimensional representations, to be greater than $1/2$ and implies a certain decay rate for $\nu(\Omega_n)$ as the dimension $n$ grows. However, I'm searching for a more quantitative understanding of these decay rates.
Is it possible to derive explicit functions $f(n, AD(\Gamma))$ that bound $\nu(\Omega_n)$ from above, given the constraint on $AD(\Gamma)$? Do specific decay behaviors (polynomial, exponential, etc.) emerge as a consequence of this constraint? I wonder if the decay rates are also influenced by other structural aspects of $\Gamma$, such as the order of its commutator subgroup.
Any insights on this interplay between Plancherel measure decay and the specific range of $AD(\Gamma)$ would be greatly appreciated.

To capture this decay, we could introduce a parameter $\alpha > 0$ and try to establish a bound of the form: $$\nu(\Omega_n) \leq \frac{C(AD(\Gamma))}{n^{2+\alpha}} \quad \text{for } n \geq 2$$

Thanks for the interest in results/questions in my paper. There seem to be some misunderstandings: having $1 < {\rm AD}(\Gamma)<2$ forces $\nu(\Omega_1)$ to be strictly between $0$ and $1$, but it is not true that $\nu(\Omega_1) >1/2$. In fact, if you look at Proposition 3.9 in the linked paper, it says that if $\nu(\Omega_1)<1$ then $\nu(\Omega_1) \leq 1/2$; this is an analogue of the fact that in a finite non-abelian group, the derived subgroup has cardinality $\geq 2$.

Also, for a virtually abelian $\Gamma$ we always have $\nu(\Omega_n)=0$ for all $n$ greater than some $d$ that depends on $\Gamma$, so it feels a bit misleading to talk about "decay rates" of $\nu(\Omega_n)$ as $n$ grows. What is meaningful, and I think has been done for finite groups, is to seek upper bounds on $\nu(\Omega_n)$ as a function of ${\rm AD}(\Gamma)$ and $n$ where the function $f$ does not depend on $\Gamma$: I think this is really what you are asking for?
